# PureScript - Pattern match arrays of unknown length

Tags: purescript

Is there a way to pattern match arrays of an unknown length in PureScript? As an example, here's how I would do it with a `List` in Haskell:

```
addFirstTwo :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
addFirstTwo (x:y:_) = x + y
```

I tried something similar (using `Array a` instead of `[a]`) in PureScript, but got the following error:

> Operator Data.Array.(:) cannot be used in a pattern as it is an alias for function Data.Array.cons.
>   Only aliases for data constructors may be used in patterns.

I know I can use `List`s in PureScript instead of Arrays, but I'd like to pattern match with arrays. I didn't see how to do this after reading the [Array pattern matching section of PureScript by Example](https://leanpub.com/purescript/read#leanpub-auto-array-patterns).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Array cons patterns have been removed from the language long ago. You can use `uncons` from `Data.Array` instead, like so:

```haskell
case uncons xs of
  Just {head: x, tail} ->
    case uncons tail of
      Just {head: y, tail: _} -> x + y
      Nothing -> 0
  Nothing -> 0
```

But beware that `uncons` ∈ *Θ(n)*.

Alternatively you can use `take` from `Data.Array`:

```haskell
case take 2 xs of
  [a, b] -> a + b
  _ -> 0
```

`take` ∈ *Θ(min(n, m))* (in this case m = 2).

Or even `(!!)` from `Data.Array`:

```haskell
case xs !! 0, xs !! 1 of
  Just x, Just y -> x + y
  _, _ -> 0
```

In general lists are more pleasant to work with than arrays are.